# Mongoengine How to Filter with ISODate

Tags: mongodb-query, mongoengine

I'm trying to convert a query string into Mongoengine. The filter is looking at an array to limit to a lifecycle match and enable_date is null or enable_date is less than or equal to an ISODate

```
filter = { "integration" : { "$elemMatch" : { "lifecycle" : lifecycle, "$or" : [ { "enable_date" : None}, {"enable_date" : { "$lte" : ISODate(f"{as_of_date}")} }  ] } }}         
    subs = Collection.objects(__raw__=filter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use queryset visitor from mongoengine

```
from datetime import datetime
from mongoengine.queryset.visitor import Q
subs = Collection.objects(Q(lifecycle=lifecycle) & (Q(enable_date=None) | Q(enable_date__lte=datetime.now())))
```